# What are some good resources on using Lucene.Net?

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

Does anyone know where I can find out more information on Lucene.Net?

I am looking for a tutorial or videos on how to use Lucene.Net that stack overflow users can personally recommend.

Answer (score 21):

There are some great articles on CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/lucene-net-in-asp-net.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_analysis.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_custom_analyzer.aspx

There are more if you enter Lucene in their search.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're referring to the following: ([link replaced; site closed](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)).
The page seems to contain all the information you might want to know about the project and its status.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, [setting up a SOLR instance](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) can be useful, too. It's based on Lucene and is a Java Web application that provides a REST-style API for querying and updating its contents. We use it for faceted searching on our company's Web site; Zappos and NetFlix use it as well, I believe.